# History: what is the meaning of the name 'xargs'?

Tags: xargs, history

The common unix utility program grep is an abbreviation of "globally search a regular expression and print", which makes grep a case of "does what it says on the tin". The name informs us of the functionality of the program.

Is there a similar history behind the name of 'xargs'? Does the name have any meaning that helps as mnemonic in the same way as grep does?

Comment: I have no source for it, but I had assumed that "x" represented the multiplication or "times" symbol, and "args" was "arguments".

Comment: Best reference found:  "The name xargs, pronounced EX-args, means “combine arguments.”" From the [Overview](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/manual/html_node/find_html/Overview.html#Overview) in GNU `findutils` manual.

Comment: A better reference to consult is the _SVID_.

Comment: The [man index in pwb1 unix](https://www.tuhs.org/cgi-bin/utree.pl?file=PWB1/usr/man/man0/index) says "xargs(I): construct  argument list(s) and execute command", so it looks like it's "execute-args". But there's no indication that its authors haven't use the `x` just for euphony ;-)

Comment: A better venue for such questions would be the tuhs mailing list, where you may obtain such info directly from the people who invented it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The description in the Unix System 5 administrator's reference manual, the X/Open *Portability Guide*, and the *System V Interface Definition* is:

> xargs — construct argument list(s) and execute command

These pre-date by years [Wolfram Roesler's 1993 *Unix Acronym List*](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.unix.misc/J4EJEOMdhXU/dkYObT6HGEYJ) which calls it "extended arguments".  As does [Gordon A. Moffet's `xargs` clone published in 1986](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/mod.sources/UR_Mypm9n7w/pJuZ10rM09kJ) whose manual says:

> xargs — execute a command with many arguments

**However**: Whilst the System 5 doco and the clone doco might lead one to conclude that yes "x" relates to "execute", "extend" per Wolfram Roesler's *Unix Acronym List* is in fact more likely the case.  [Herb Gellis's own commentary on the subject](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.unix.questions/vG2keVnENmo/LkZN5orQrwcJ) implies that xe wrote it to *extend* the then limit of 512 bytes on filename expansion in the Mashey shell.

[Herb Gellis](https://www.linkedin.com/in/herbgellis) is apparently still alive.  You could ask xem.  ☺

Answer (score 2):

Xargs means: eXtended ARGumentS.

Comment: Do you have a source for this claim? Like Max M's answer, this sounds plausible, but it would be nice to know if this is mentioned in some manual or other official description of xargs.

Comment: Not now, or: not from an Unix manual. If I find something .....

Comment: This may be of help: http://www.roesler-ac.de/wolfram/acro/Cmd.htm

Comment: An old book reference: http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/unix11.html

Answer (score 1):

`xargs` means "execute arguments". Some commands can not take input straight from the standard input but only as arguments (e.g. `echo`, `rm`). `xargs` converts data from the standard input into executable arguments and tells the following command to execute those arguments.

Comment: This sounds plausible, do you know if there is a source for this claim?

Comment: No, xargs does not "execute argumens". It executes a command (echo by default) with the list of arguments from stdin. (-1).

Comment: @Isaac: It doesn't execute the arguments. It tells the following command to execute those arguments.

Comment: @Rasmus Källqvist: Just what a quick internet search spits out. E.g. https://www.dingoanddonk.com/command-line-crash-course/, https://ugoproto.github.io/ugodoc/Command%20Line%20Crash%20Course/, https://www.quia.com/jg/2796502list.html

Comment: An old book reference:  http://www.netzmafia.de/skripten/unix/unix11.html

Comment: @MaxM Exactly, it doesn't "execute arguments".

Comment: From the man-page: "xargs reads items from the standard input, delimited by blanks (which can be protected with double or single quotes or a backslash) or newlines, and executes the command (default is /bin/echo) one or more times with any initial-arguments followed by items read from standard input. " It even has an argument --max-procs that sets the number of processes to be executed. @Rasmus Källqvist: Sorry, this isn't that important to me. Please take this input and make up your own mind.